# How To Cause Click Events When Numbers Are Input In Visual Basic 6

Tags: textbox, command

I was wondering how I could cause a click event in Visual Basic 6, When a number is input into a text box. I am creating a currency converter and instead of having to click a button to calculate the answer, I would like it so when you input a number, It automatically calculates it, Without the need of clicking anything. There would be two Textboxes, One for input and one for output, I would like it so that when a number is input into the first textbox, It would be calculated and the answer automatically output into the second textbox, Without clicking anything. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Change event in the input textbox. A sample code follows:

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()
    ' get characters from textbox
        Dim text As String
        text = Text1.text

    ' if we have a number
        If IsNumeric(text) Then
            ' convert characters to numbers
                Dim inputNumber As Double
                inputNumber = text

            ' calculate
                Dim answer As Double
                answer = calculate(inputNumber)
        End If
End Sub

Private Function calculate(number As Double)
    ' -----------------------------------
    ' Your calculation here
    ' -----------------------------------
End Function
```